# Remove delete button for first div?

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` which is being cloned

```
<div id="duplicater">
  <label>Number:</label>
  <input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity"/>
  <button id="removebutton" class='remove'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

The first time the page loads it will show the first div.
If you click the "add" button it will clone the entire `div`.

But it has a delete button, which is showing for all cloned `div`s. I *don't* want to show that delete button for the first main `div`.

How to do it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  jQuery('#add').click(function() {
    var button = jQuery('#duplicater').clone();
    id++;
    button.removeAttr('id');
    button.insertBefore('.new_item_details');
    button.attr('id', 'new_' + id).attr('data-id', id);
    button.find('.remove').attr('data-id', id);
  });
  jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    var thisId = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery('div[data-id="' + thisId + '"]').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="duplicater">
  <label>Number:</label>
  <input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity" />
  <button id="removebutton" class='remove'>Delete</button>
</div>
<div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details">
</div>
```

[codepen for this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwjgyJ)

Comment: dont clone the delete button, append it in your jquery

Comment: Why not just using as CSS rule `#duplicater .remove { display: none; }`

Comment: and another option (if you don't like css) - add `style='display:none;'` to your button, then set to display:block in your clone code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with below link may be it can help you

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nq929m5/2/)

HTML Code

```
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="duplicater">
  <label>Number:</label>
  <input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity" />
</div>
<div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    var button = $('#duplicater').clone();
    id++;
    button.removeAttr('id');
    button.insertBefore('.new_item_details');
    button.attr('id', 'new_' + id).attr('data-id', id);
    button.append("<button id='removebutton' class='remove'>Delete</button>");
    button.find('.remove').attr('data-id', id);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    var thisId = $(this).data('id');
    $('div[data-id="' + thisId + '"]').remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would feel more comfortable relying on javascript to do this versus just CSS. That's just my opinion. Unless you actually need to assign `IDs` for some other use, I wouldn't since there's no need for them in this case. You can just use the `$(this).parent().remove()` function in jQuery. That will remove the element without having to target any certain `ID`, etc.

Your HTML code would look something like this:

```
  <div style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <button id="add">add</button>
  </div>

  <div id="duplicater">
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity"/>
  </div>

  <div id="new_item_details" class="new_item_details">
  </div>
```

And your javascript code would look something like this:

```
$("#add").click(function() {

  var c = $("#duplicater").clone();
  c.append("<button id='removebutton' class='remove'>Delete</button>");
  c.insertBefore("#new_item_details");

});


$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {

  $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

Very clean and condense code. Here's a **jsbin** for you to use:

http://jsbin.com/pivefasebi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

try below css:

```
#duplicater:first-of-type .remove{display:none}
```

this css not display a delete button of the first duplicater div element.

I hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  jQuery('#add').click(function() {
    var button = jQuery('#duplicater').clone();
    id++;
    button.removeAttr('id');
    button.insertBefore('.new_item_details').append('<button id="removebutton" class="remove">Delete</button>');
button.attr('id', 'new_' + id).attr('data-id', id);
button.find('.remove').attr('data-id', id);
 });
jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
var thisId = jQuery(this).data('id');
jQuery('div[data-id="' + thisId + '"]').remove();
e.preventDefault();
});


});



<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="duplicater">
<label>Number:</label>
<input type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity"/>

</div>
<div id="new_item_details" class ="new_item_details">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this using CSS.

```
#duplicater #removebutton {
  display: none;
}
```